# how to convert an array to string including space elements in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string, ecmascript-6

I want to convert this array into string includes space elements in javascript. space doesn't show after return.

```
let results = ['Hello',' ',' ',' ','EveryOne',' ',' ',' ','My',' ','Name',' ','is',' ','X'];

const result = () => 
{
    for(let i = 0; i<results.length; i++)
    {
        return results;
    } 
 } 

result();

// Expected Output : "Hello   EveryOne   My  Name is X";
```

Comment: Perhaps also show expected output in your question. Because if you want duplicitous spaces then thats not all clear

Comment: Ok i see you show expected out put. You can use standard array function for join

Comment: Your code has syntax errors which make it hard to help you. Please fix the syntax errors. But the short answer is: Just use `join("")`. That will not remove the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `reactjs` tag is there, am assuming issue rendering. Use HTML entity   for ' ', that should display correct as in snippet.

```js
const Component = () => {
  let results = [
    "Hello",
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    "EveryOne",
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    "My",
    " ",
    "Name",
    " ",
    "is",
    " ",
    "X",
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      {results.map((word) => (
        word === ' ' ? <span>&nbsp;</span> : <span> { word } </span>
      ))}{" "}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"> </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

use `Array.prototype.join` with empty string as separator:

```js
const result = () => {
    let results = ['Hello',' ',' ',' ','EveryOne',' ',' ',' ','My',' ','Name',' ','is',' ','X'];
    return results.join('')
 } 
 
 console.log(result())
```

Comment: If you dont care about repetitive whitespace as seems to be the case, then here is the solution @SilentStorm

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate the elements in the `for-loop`:

```js
const result = (results=[]) => {
  let str = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    str += results[i];
  } 
  return str;
} 
 
console.log( result(['Hello',' ',' ',' ','EveryOne',' ',' ',' ','My',' ','Name',' ','is',' ','X']) );
```

Another way using [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
const result = (results=[]) => {
  return results.join('');
} 
 
console.log( result(['Hello',' ',' ',' ','EveryOne',' ',' ',' ','My',' ','Name',' ','is',' ','X']) );
```

Comment: But OP seems to want the repetitive white space where it occurs. Scratching my head on why but seems to be the desired result on even if two or more spaces included in the string result between tokens

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your array to string, and then split commas per something like: `results.toString().split(',').join('');`

Answer (score 0):

```
 let result = arr.filter(item => {
    if (item !== " "){
        return item
    };
  });
  console.log("result",result)
```

Comment: It's good practice on StackOverflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work.

Comment: Answer's are great. But for best practices, please provide an explanation. You only posting code makes the OP and future commers copy and paste your answer without understanding the logic behind the answer. Please provide an answer with some explanation. Thank You!